# Is there any chat/messaging plugin for Cake 2.x?

Tags: cakephp, chat, cakephp-2.0, messaging

I'm looking for a messaging plugin for cakephp. So far I've found a couple of plugins (for example here 
http://plugins.cakephp.org/packages?query=chat), but they are all out-dated and work with cake 1.2.

Is there one for Cake 2.x ?

Comment: Cos, did you ever find anything?

Comment: Hello bowlerae, I didn't find anything cakephp specific that wasn't outdated. I finally settled on using something similar to this: http://anantgarg.com/2009/05/13/gmail-facebook-style-jquery-chat/ (Simple PHP with MySQL and jQuery)

Comment: The whole point of opensource and GitHub is to be able to use existing code and improving on it. Could you please fork one of the CakePHP 1.2 chat plugins and upgrade it to CakePHP 2.x ? That would really help out the community. Or at least publish your plugin to GitHub and link to it from here.

Comment: Third party, check this and very easy to integrate just 2 mins work  http://www.livechatinc.com/

Answer (score 0):

See the bellow links i think they are helpful:

 1. https://github.com/zuha/Messages-Zuha-Cakephp-Plugin

 2. https://github.com/skitle/CakePHP-Messaging-Plugin

Answer (score 0):

what about this ? http://www.cometchat.com/cakephp-chat

It is not free but this is what i found ...

Otherways you could integrate Node.JS and Socket.IO in CakePHP as JS Libraries and work with to build a chat application ...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try this plugin:

https://github.com/angelxmoreno/CakePHP-PrivateMessages

Comment: Sorry, it's empty package